# Specific Word Extraction from a text file C#

Tags: c#, console-application

I currently have a method I am building that goes through a text file using streamreader. I want to use either regex or something similar to change the current method which you'll see just below here.

```
using (StreamReader fs = File.OpenText(FilePath))
    {

        int count = 0; //counts the number of times wordResponse is found.
        int lineNumber = 0;
        while (!fs.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = fs.ReadLine();
            lineNumber++;
            int position = line.IndexOf(WordSearch);
            if (position != -1)
            {
                count++;
                Console.WriteLine("Match#{0} line {1}: {2}", count, lineNumber, line);
            }
        }

        if (count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("your word was not found!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your word was found " + count + " times!");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

the output I get from the current method is:

```
Match#1 line 3: Proin eleifend tortor velit, **True** quis aliquam arcu congue ut. Fusce sed mattis purus, sed vehicula diam. Nullam in leo sit amet massa pharetra semper et vel diam.
Match#2 line 7: lobortis nisl. Fusce dignissim ligula **True** a nunc maximus, vitae sollicitudin erat dictum. Vivamus commodo massa a tellus gravida posuere.
Match#3 line 17: **True** Sed pellentesque ipsum vel neque accumsan, quis fermentum augue pretium. Praesent fermentum risus nec ultricies sodales.
Match#4 line 24: Fusce nulla risus, ornare in eleifend id, **True** tincidunt eu sem. Donec enim sapien, rhoncus vitae ex lobortis, sagittis molestie libero.
Your word was found 4 times!
Press enter to quit.
```

As you can see I get the entire line of code, when all I want is a single word from each sentence. The word it is searching for right now is **True**

I believe it is the string `string line = fs.ReadLine();` I have to manipulate a few extra steps to get the result I want.

Any tips or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please be more clear about what you are looking for?

Comment: "all I want is a single word from each sentence." - Which word... the word you're searching with??

Comment: @RyanSearle A word you input manually earlier in the program. It looks through each line of a file **which you give as input** and looks for a specific word **which you give as input** the word it is looking for right now is true as I'll edit into bold in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It it as easy as.....?

```
Console.WriteLine("Match#{0} line {1}: {2}", count, lineNumber, WordSearch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this after int position =...

```
var word = line.SubString(position, Word.Length)
```

Then

```
Console.WriteLine("Match#{0} line {1}: {2}", count, lineNumber, word);
```

Comment: He is not using or indicating regex.  'IndexOf' kind of shows an exact matching, a partial matching with regex or similar would show 'match'.  Sort of like: 'var regexPercent = New Regex("^(?!.{8,})[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*$") If !regexPercent.Match(textValue).Success (do something)'

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use either regex or something similar...

Since you mention an interest in changing your current implementation to use a regular expression I'll offer up this snippet:

```cs
var matches = Regex.Match(line, $".*({WordSearch})\\b.*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (matches.Captures.Count > 0)
{
    count++;
    Console.WriteLine($"Match#{count} line {lineNumber}: {matches.Groups[1]}");
}
```

The `RegexOption.IgnoreCase` in the `Match` constructor seemed appropriate along with adding the `\b` in the expression to limit partial matches.